# Passing an array from a struct as an argument to a function

Tags: arrays, c, struct, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int votes;
}
candidate;

void array_function(int arr[]);

int main(void)
{
    candidate candidates[3];
    candidates[0].votes = 5;
    candidates[1].votes = 3;
    candidates[2].votes= 1;
    print_array_function(candidates.votes);
}

void print_array_function(int arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to run this code which declares a struct, feeds values into it and tries to pass an array inside the struct to a function. However, on doing so I get the following error:

```
test.c:22:30: error: member reference base type 'candidate [3]' is not a structure or union
    array_function(candidates.votes);
```

How do I pass this structs array into the function?

Comment: Your struct *does not contain* an array. You can’t just treat the members of structs inside an array as an array of values. The error message says exactly that: `candidates` is of type *array* (more precisely, `candidate[3]`), it is *not* a struct type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare the function like

```
void array_function( const candidate arr[], size_t n );
```

and call like

```
print_array_function( candidates, 3 );
```

The function can be defined the following way

```
void array_function( const candidate arr[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%i\n", arr[i].votes );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to send only candidates.vote instead of the entire struct?

Comment: @ZohairUlHasan Why are you trying to write an obfuscated code? In general it can be incorrect because the alignment of the structure can be specified differently.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have an array of structure `candidate` which each element contains a single `int` called `votes` (certainly `vote` would be a better name for it). Maybe the best approach to do what you want is to create a function `print_candidate_array_vote` as :

```
void print_candidate_array_vote(candidate *candidates, unsigned int n_candidates)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n_candidates; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", candidates[i].votes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, have made some changes

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct candidate
 {
 int votes;
 }
candidate;

void array_function(int arr[]);

int main(void)
{
    candidate candidates[3];
    candidates[0].votes = 5;
    candidates[1].votes = 3;
    candidates[2].votes= 1;
    print_array_function(candidates);
}

void print_array_function(candidate arr[])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   {
       printf("%i\n", arr[i]);
   }
}
```